# Vorkosigan Saga - Ivan Vorpatril Vote Fixing

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, vorkosigan-saga, lois-mcmaster-bujold

I recall that Ivan Vorpatril lives in an apartment block that was part of a scheme where the vote of area residents was threatened by the machinations of some Vor party.  Something about enclosing the properties as part of the Vor's particular house disenfranchising the residents from a local election?

I can't find particulars, and I worry that I might actually be recalling Fanon rather than Canon.

Please point me at the location in canon where this event took place, or assure me that it is not, in fact, canon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like Fanon. The most we ever really hear about Ivan's apartment is in Lord Vorpatril's Alliance. His mother owns the building and has one of the apartments, as does he, the building is located in Vorbarra Sultana, and the other apartments are mostly rented out for some income. And, obviously, that it is rather luxurious.

What you might be thinking of is various mentions of Lady Alice's soirée's, where Lady Alice will bring influence upon the Counts and especially the Wives of the Counts. She does so in order to help influence elections and such. But it's not a vote fixing scheme.

Comment: Thank you.  Thus convinced to stop looking for a canon source, I found the fanfic source of my recollection: _'So he put a fence around the whole block and declared the whole thing Vorlane House, and untaxable. ...  Was Vorlane going to declare them all his subjects by manorial right, and demand their oaths? ...and bar them from the civic elections?'_ --  http://archiveofourown.org/works/225955